# add value to listbox from between two dates and name each time

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have userform of which there is two textboxes of you enter the two between dates and combobox1 to select name from column H and user finds the matched date in Column against name in column H however it wont add any data to listbox to show all the data matched with the date between two dates searched with name. it is just loops and then ends the macro, can someone help me please

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim tarih1, tarih2 As Date:
 Dim sh As range
 LastRow As Long
 Dim s1 As Worksheet
 
  Set s1 = Worksheets("VehicleRejected")
 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Or TextBox2.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You need to add the beginning and end dates", vbCritical, ""
    Exit Sub
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a product from drop-down list", vbDefaultButton1, ""
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Call uzat
    tarih1 = VBA.Format(TextBox1.Value)
    tarih2 = VBA.Format(TextBox2.Value)
   
    ListBox1.Clear
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 9
    ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "30;70;140;30;80;65;80;65;60"
    
    LastRow = s1.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each sh In s1.range("A5:A" & LastRow)
    
    If CLng(CDate(sh.Value)) >= CLng(CDate(tarih1)) And _
    CLng(CDate(sh.Value)) <= CLng(CDate(tarih2)) And _
    CStr(sh.Offset(0, 0).Value) = CStr(ComboBox1.Text) Then
    
ListBox1.AddItem
     
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = sh.Offset(0, 0)
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Offset(0, 1)
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Offset(0, 2)
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Offset(0, 3)
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Offset(0, 4)
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh.Offset(0, 5)
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = sh.Offset(0, 6)
            ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 8) = sh.Offset(0, 7)
          
        End If
        
 Next sh
 

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full code, some sample data

Comment: Hi Ricardo Thank you for your promote reply. i have placed complete userform code. please help if you can as i am really stuck for past 2 weeks now and i am not an expert on vba

Comment: Hi Harin. Please add some sample data. It's hard to tell without knowing what's in the `sh` range

Comment: Hi Ricardo thank you, please see below link of the sample book. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YWZzaFf-FkqDey2qVmYyAJThaJmAeU-aDLVFNKFVak/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What column refers to the product in the combo box?

Comment: sh range is referring to dates on sheet called "VehicleRejected" in column A and combobox1 is referring to names in column H

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your userform and this is the code that resulted

---

**Some suggestions first:**

- Name your userform controls to something meaninful (Textbox1 is hard to understand whether startDate it's easier)
- Name your variables to something meaningful (sh is hard to understand, sourceRange it's easier)
- Indent your code properly (you can use [Rubberduckvba.com](http://Rubberduckvba.com)) to help you with data
- Try to break your code into pieces (e.g. first validate, then prepare, then add items)
- Comment your code

---

**Some disclaimers:**

- The way you're loading the userform is not recommended, when you feel more confortable with programming in VBA check [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

---

**How to proceed:**

- Read the code's comments
- Step into it adding a break point and pressing `F8` key
- Adjust it to fit your needs

---

Add this behind your userform code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Validate Dates
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    startDate = CDate(IIf(TextBox1.Value = vbNullString, 0, TextBox1.Value))
    endDate = CDate(IIf(TextBox2.Value = vbNullString, 0, TextBox2.Value))
    If startDate = 0 Or endDate = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You need to add the beginning and end dates", vbCritical, ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate product
    Dim productName As String
    productName = ComboBox1.Value
    If productName = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a product from drop-down list", vbDefaultButton1, ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Prepare listbox
    Dim dataListBox As msforms.ListBox
    Set dataListBox = Me.ListBox1
    
    With dataListBox
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 9
        .ColumnWidths = "30;70;140;30;80;65;80;65;60"
        ' Add data to listbox
        AddDataToListBox dataListBox, productName, startDate, endDate
        
    End With
    
    
End Sub

Private Sub AddDataToListBox(ByVal listBoxControl As msforms.ListBox, ByVal productName As String, ByVal startDate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date)
    ' Set a reference to the vehicles worksheet
    Dim vehiclesSheet As Worksheet
    Set vehiclesSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VehicleRejected")
    
    ' Get last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = vehiclesSheet.Cells(vehiclesSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set range to evaluate
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = vehiclesSheet.Range("A5:A" & lastRow)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in range
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    For Each sourceCell In sourceRange.Cells
    
        ' Check if source cell is between dates
        If sourceCell.Value >= startDate And sourceCell.Value <= endDate Then
        
            ' Check if product matches
            If sourceCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = productName Then
                
                ' Begin a counter to add list items
                Dim counter As Long
                
                With listBoxControl
                    .AddItem
                    .List(counter, 0) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
                    ' You're missing one column here (is it on purpose?)
                    .List(counter, 2) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    .List(counter, 3) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    .List(counter, 4) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    .List(counter, 5) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    .List(counter, 6) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
                    .List(counter, 7) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
                    .List(counter, 8) = sourceCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                    
                End With
                
                counter = counter + 1
                
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next sourceCell
    
End Sub
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Ricardo Thank you very much and i really appreciate for all the coding you have re-written . just a quick question is there away to show also for all multi sheet using the dates and names?

Comment: sorry is there away to add also the all the columns show son textboxs title?

Comment: Hi, please elaborate on your questions. Maybe a sample of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Hi Ricardo Will do thank you once again. is there away to archive all data from multit tabs.e.g Sheet1, Sheet2, sheet3, sheet4 when you select date and name match and shows all the data between the dates selected from all mutli sheets?

Comment: Sure, you could loop through all the sheets and ranges you need. Search for `For each` loops

Comment: sorry where do i need to write this in the code? can i add the subject title in the list box for each columns title?

Comment: list box header

Comment: I suggest that you post another question, detailing what you’re trying to achieve